# Problems starting MongoDB on Windows

Tags: mongodb

I did the mongodb installation, but when I try to start in windows 10 console, the log shows me the following:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>"C:\Program
>   Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\mongod.exe" 2017-12-13T11:09:06.089-0700
>   I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=11240 port=27017
>   dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=DESKTOP-5GUM84N
>   2017-12-13T11:09:06.089-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS:
>   Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2 2017-12-13T11:09:06.090-0700 I
>   CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.0
>   2017-12-13T11:09:06.091-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version:
>   a57d8e71e6998a2d0afde7edc11bd23e5661c915 2017-12-13T11:09:06.092-0700
>   I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1u-fips  22
>   Sep 2016 2017-12-13T11:09:06.092-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>   allocator: tcmalloc 2017-12-13T11:09:06.092-0700 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] modules: none 2017-12-13T11:09:06.093-0700 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] build environment: 2017-12-13T11:09:06.093-0700 I
>   CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
>   2017-12-13T11:09:06.094-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch:
>   x86_64 2017-12-13T11:09:06.095-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>   target_arch: x86_64 2017-12-13T11:09:06.095-0700 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] options: {} 2017-12-13T11:09:06.100-0700 I -
>   [initandlisten] Detected data files in C:\data\db\ created by the
>   'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to
>   'wiredTiger'. 2017-12-13T11:09:06.101-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
>   wiredtiger_open config:
>   create,cache_size=3534M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
>   2017-12-13T11:09:06.574-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger
>   message [1513188546:574263][11240:140724166549840], txn-recover: Main
>   recovery loop: starting at 10/4608 2017-12-13T11:09:06.787-0700 I
>   STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message
>   [1513188546:786400][11240:140724166549840], txn-recover: Recovering
>   log 10 through 11 2017-12-13T11:09:07.034-0700 I STORAGE 
>   [initandlisten] WiredTiger message
>   [1513188547:34042][11240:140724166549840], txn-recover: Recovering log
>   11 through 11 2017-12-13T11:09:07.732-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>   2017-12-13T11:09:07.732-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING:
>   Access control is not enabled for the database.
>   2017-12-13T11:09:07.733-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **
>   Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
>   2017-12-13T11:09:07.735-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>   2017-12-13T11:09:07.735-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING:
>   This server is bound to localhost. 2017-12-13T11:09:07.736-0700 I
>   CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to
>   connect to this server. 2017-12-13T11:09:07.736-0700 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip 
>   to specify which IP 2017-12-13T11:09:07.737-0700 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from,
>   or with --bind_ip_all to 2017-12-13T11:09:07.737-0700 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior
>   is desired, start the 2017-12-13T11:09:07.738-0700 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable
>   this warning. 2017-12-13T11:09:07.738-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>   2017-12-13T11:09:07.739-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>   2017-12-13T11:09:07.739-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING:
>   The file system cache of this machine is configured to be greater than
>   40% of the total memory. This can lead to increased memory pressure
>   and poor performance. 2017-12-13T11:09:07.740-0700 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] See
>   http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/wt-windows-system-file-cache
>   2017-12-13T11:09:07.740-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>   2017-12-13T15:09:08.161-0300 W FTDC     [initandlisten] Failed to
>   initialize Performance Counters for FTDC: WindowsPdhError:
>   PdhExpandCounterPathW failed with 'The specified object is not
>   found on the computer.' for counter '\Memory\Available Bytes'
>   2017-12-13T15:09:08.161-0300 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing
>   full-time diagnostic data capture with directory
>   'C:/data/db/diagnostic.data' 2017-12-13T15:09:08.165-0300 I NETWORK 
>   [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017

I followed all the intructions in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#run-mongodb-community-edition
but i can't start mongodb. anyone knows how to fix this launch error ?

I hope your help guys :c

Regards!

Comment: To me, this looks like the server is up and running...?!

Comment: `[initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017` seems like a normal "running" entry, and I don't see any errors except related to performance counters.

Comment: It seems like a normal running, but the problem is in this phrase:
'[initandlisten] Failed to initialize Performance Counters for FTDC: WindowsPdhError: PdhExpandCounterPathW failed with 'The specified object is not found on the computer.' for counter '\Memory\Available Bytes' '

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your mongod actually started successfully initially in the beginning. The log output:

```
NETWORK [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

indicates that the `mongod` is online and waiting for connections on the specified port. You could have at that point opened a `mongo` shell on the same machine to connect to the `mongod`.

However, I understand that the warnings as displayed could indicate that there was an issue in operation. We've updated our documentation to address this:

You can find the documentation in question here:
[Run MongoDB Community on Windows](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#run-mongodb-community-edition)

It looks like other users have helped you with getting a good working configuration file, but I'd like to pick apart the original output to clarify any confusion encountered there.

Lets start by breaking up your original mongod process output:

```
CONTROL [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database. 2017-12-13T11:09:07.733-0700
```

This is a warning that indicates you did not start the mongod process using authentication or authorization. Since it seems like you are using the default settings for 3.6, this is an expected informational warning. Please read through the MongoDB documentation on [authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication/) when you get a chance and plan for implementing simple authentication, especially if the `mongod` will be exposed to the public internet at any point in time.

The next warning is:

```
CONTROL [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost. 2017-12-13T11:09:07.736-0700
```

By default in MongoDB 3.6, the `mongod` binds to the localhost address. In short, the `mongod` only listens for connections on the local machine. This gives you time to configure authentication before you open up your MongoDB deployment to your private network or the public internet.

As noted by other users, you can resolve this by setting the [`net.bindIp`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-compatibility/#bind-ip-compatibility) in your configuration file:

```
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

When you are ready to open the `mongod` to non-localhost connections, just append an IP address associated to a network adapter on the host machine. For example, if the host machine has a network adapter 192.168.1.15, you can add that to `bindIp`. This tells the `mongod` to listen for incoming connections on both addresses.

```
net:
  bindIp: "127.0.0.1,192.168.1.15"
```

As far as the FTDC warning, the `\Memory\Available Bytes` counter is related to Windows Performance Management - you can read more about that [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb734903.aspx). You may need to configure some Windows components to enable that counter. Its also possible that the counter is only available (or accessible) in the Server architectures of Windows.

The warning is informational and should not impact normal operations, unless you are heavily reliant on FTDC data for your work.

You can find more information on log messages in MongoDB in our [Log Message documentation.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for your information bro, I hope work without problems ;)

Comment: Excelent answer!

Comment: BTW, the FTDC warning may be related to Windows using language specific performance counter names while mongodb uses english identifiers. So far as regards technical aspects. What I think about absolutely useless limited translations on the one hand and obvious ignorance of non-US cultures (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27354) on the other hand is quite another story.

Answer (score 2):

i believe this message is from mongod(mongodb server).

and now you have to run mongo.exe inside "bin"folder to connect to the server(with mongod on, don't close the window) in order to start mongodb.

make sure you created a mongod.cfg inside C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\mongod.cfg

which is from **step 3 Create a configuration file.**

open that file and type those things below to mongod.cfg

```
systemLog:
 destination: file
 path: c:\data\log\mongod.cfg
storage:
 dbPath: c:\data\db
```

if there's still error try to copy and past these code inside mongod.cfg:

```
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: c:\data\log\mongod.cfg
   logAppend: true
storage:
   journal:
      enabled: true
processManagement:
   fork: true
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27017
setParameter:
   enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
```

Comment: I try your solution but it showing me the same message. 

In mongod.exe show me the same error, but mongo.exe shows me the following:


** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
 **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
 ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
**          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.
 **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP
**          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to

Comment: **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
 **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
 ** WARNING: The file system cache of this machine is configured to be greater than 40% of the total memory. This can lead to increased memory pressure and poor performance.
See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/wt-windows-system-file-cache
452-0300 E -        [main] Error loading history file: FileOpenFailed: Unable to fopen() file C:\Users\rodri/.dbshell: The system can not find the specified file.'

Comment: are you sure you followed full steps? incluide configure C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\mongod.cfg file?

Comment: Yes, I have the cfg file with this information included:

storage:
   journal:
      enabled: true

Is correct ?

Comment: i posted the code which you should have in C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\mongod.cfg. you can copy and past in manually.

Comment: Ok, I copied and pasted your code in my cfg file located in C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\mongod.cfg and now it looks like this:

systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: c:\data\log\mongod.log
storage:
 dbPath: c:\data\db
   journal:
      enabled: true
      wiredTiger:
        cacheSizeGB: 0.5

What do you think if I erase the "journal code"?

(Thank you for be patient bro)

Comment: yep , rewrite entire file and leave only those codes in(code that i posted above). then try to start mongod.exe and mongo.exe again and see if you are getting same problem("no problem ;)")

Comment: Thank you bro! Your solution worked partially, now the only problem that I have is this line: 
[initandlisten] Failed to initialize Performance Counters for FTDC: WindowsPdhError: PdhExpandCounterPathW failed with 'The specified object was not found on the computer.' for counter '\Memory\Available Bytes'
I create a database with mydb name to testing and the db was created fine, and I did "insert()" and works fine too.
Now I can create and insert data in the database, so I think that this error is not a problem to continue working. 
What do you think bro ?

Comment: there's many harmless error in web develop. Many of them have ocurred to me and others. and some of thosedon't have  a perfect solution yet it doesn't really matters so people just moved on for those "harmless error" as they works with their objects.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support on this bro, your information was very useful for me :D Have a nice day!

Comment: No problem mate ;)  glad i can help.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your mongod.cfg

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: "127.0.0.1"
```

Then the MONGO command can connect to the local instance.

Comment: I edited the mongod.cfg with your code and still not working :'( Anyway, since the beggining mongo recognized the localhost connection with those data