# MongoDB server startup warning

Tags: mongodb

I got those error when I try to start `mongo`:

```
Server has startup warnings:
2018-03-03T02:44:35.918+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-03-03T02:44:35.918+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2018-03-03T02:44:35.919+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2018-03-03T02:44:35.919+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-03-03T02:44:35.919+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2018-03-03T02:44:35.919+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.
2018-03-03T02:44:35.920+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP
2018-03-03T02:44:35.921+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2018-03-03T02:44:35.922+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2018-03-03T02:44:35.923+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2018-03-03T02:44:35.924+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-03-03T02:44:35.925+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-03-03T02:44:35.925+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: The file system cache of this machine is configured to be greater than 40% of the total memory. This can lead to increased memory pressure and poor performance.
2018-03-03T02:44:35.926+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/wt-windows-system-file-cache
2018-03-03T02:44:35.927+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

Comment: Try to run it under admin mode.

Comment: is it any problem for database. Actually i'm new in mongoDB..!

Comment: There is not problem there. Someone posted a very similar question and the answer she had is pretty good, here it is https://stackoverflow.com/a/47830670/7127519

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warnings are pretty clear
By default you havent restricted actions for read and writ.
Your server is in your local machine and outer machines cant access to your pc.
The default cache size config is lsrge for your memory