# Error when starting MongoDB Database locally on windows 10

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to install MongoDB on Windows 10 and I'm getting this log in the command line after running "mongod" in the "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin":

> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:31.629-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire
> specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:32.889-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling
> TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols
> 'none'"} {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:32.900-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP
> FastOpen in use."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:32.923-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered
> PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:32.923-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered
> PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:32.924-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered
> PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:32.924-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading
> initialized"} {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:32.924-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB
> starting","attr":{"pid":7216,"port":27017,"dbPath":"C:/data/db/","architecture":"64-bit","host":"DESKTOP-NEDA7LG"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:32.925-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23398,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target
> operating system minimum version","attr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows
> 7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:32.925-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build
> Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.0","gitVersion":"e61bf27c2f6a83fed36e5a13c008a32d563babe2","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:32.925-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating
> System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Microsoft Windows 10","version":"10.0
> (build 19044)"}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:32.926-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set
> by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:32.932-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage
> engine to use detected by data
> files","attr":{"dbpath":"C:/data/db/","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:32.934-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening
> WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=7586M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,remove=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=2000),statistics_log=(wait=0),json_output=(error,message),verbose=[recovery_progress:1,checkpoint_progress:1,compact_progress:1,backup:0,checkpoint:0,compact:0,evict:0,history_store:0,recovery:0,rts:0,salvage:0,tiered:0,timestamp:0,transaction:0,verify:0,log:0],"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:33.290-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger
> opened","attr":{"durationMillis":356}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:33.291-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger
> recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:33.296-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WT",
> "id":4366408, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"No table logging settings
> modifications are required for existing WiredTiger
> tables","attr":{"loggingEnabled":true}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:33.310-03:00"},"s":"W",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access
> control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data
> and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:33.311-03:00"},"s":"W",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22140,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"This server
> is bound to localhost. Remote systems will be unable to connect to
> this server. Start the server with --bind_ip  to specify
> which IP addresses it should serve responses from, or with
> --bind_ip_all to bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this
> warning","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:33.329-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915702, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Updated
> wire
> specification","attr":{"oldSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true},"newSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":17,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":17,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:33.330-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":5853300, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"current
> featureCompatibilityVersion
> value","attr":{"featureCompatibilityVersion":"6.0","context":"startup"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:33.332-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"STORAGE",  "id":5071100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Clearing
> temp directory"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:33.333-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow
> Control is enabled on this deployment"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:33.667-03:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"FTDC",
> "id":23718,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to initialize
> Performance Counters for
> FTDC","attr":{"error":{"code":179,"codeName":"WindowsPdhError","errmsg":"PdhAddEnglishCounterW
> failed with 'O objeto especificado não foi encontrado no
> computador.'"}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:33.668-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",
> "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time
> diagnostic data
> capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"C:/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:33.694-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":6015317, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Setting new configuration
> state","attr":{"newState":"ConfigReplicationDisabled","oldState":"ConfigPreStart"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:33.694-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp
> monitor starting"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:33.697-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening
> on","attr":{"address":"127.0.0.1"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:33.697-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for
> connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.517-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23372,   "ctx":"thread43","msg":"Ctrl-C signal"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.518-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23371,   "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Received
> event, will terminate after current command
> ends","attr":{"controlCode":"CTRL_C_EVENT"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.518-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":4784900, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Stepping down the
> ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.524-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":4794602, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Attempting to enter
> quiesce mode"} {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.524-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"-",        "id":6371601, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down the FLE Crud thread pool"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.524-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down the MirrorMaestro"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.525-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down the WaitForMajorityService"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.525-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784903, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down the LogicalSessionCache"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.526-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,
> "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening
> sockets"} {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.526-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down the global connection pool"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.526-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.526-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",
> "id":20520,   "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Stopping further Flow
> Control ticket acquisitions."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.526-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784908, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down the PeriodicThreadToAbortExpiredTransactions"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.527-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":4784909, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting down the
> ReplicationCoordinator"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.527-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784910, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down the ShardingInitializationMongoD"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.528-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":4784911, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Enqueuing the
> ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.529-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",
> "id":4784912, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Killing all operations
> for shutdown"} {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.532-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"-",        "id":4695300,
> "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Interrupted all currently running
> operations","attr":{"opsKilled":3}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.532-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"TENANT_M", "id":5093807, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down all TenantMigrationAccessBlockers on global shutdown"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.533-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784913, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down all open transactions"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.534-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":4784914, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Acquiring the
> ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.534-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",
> "id":4784915, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting down the
> IndexBuildsCoordinator"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.535-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.535-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.536-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",
> "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all
> outstanding egress activity."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.537-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.537-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down free monitoring"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.538-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20609,   "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down free monitoring"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.539-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down the HealthLog"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.540-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down the TTL monitor"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.540-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",
> "id":3684100, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting down TTL
> collection monitor thread"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.540-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",
> "id":3684101, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Finished shutting down
> TTL collection monitor thread"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.541-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6278511, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down the Change Stream Expired Pre-images Remover"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.541-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929,
> "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for
> shutdown"} {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.542-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784930, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down the storage engine"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.542-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22320,   "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down journal flusher thread"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.543-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22321,   "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Finished
> shutting down journal flusher thread"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.546-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22322,   "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down checkpoint thread"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.547-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22323,   "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Finished
> shutting down checkpoint thread"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.547-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20282,
> "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Deregistering all the collections"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.548-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22261,
> "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Timestamp monitor shutting down"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.548-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22317,
> "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.549-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22318,   "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down session sweeper thread"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.549-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22319,   "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Finished
> shutting down session sweeper thread"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.550-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795902, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Closing
> WiredTiger","attr":{"closeConfig":"leak_memory=true,"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.567-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795901,
> "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"WiredTiger
> closed","attr":{"durationMillis":17}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.567-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22281,
> "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"shutdown: removing fs lock..."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.567-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",
> "id":4784931, "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Dropping the scope cache
> for shutdown"} {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.568-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"FTDC",     "id":20626,   "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down full-time diagnostic data capture"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.572-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Now
> exiting"} {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.572-03:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"consoleTerminate","msg":"Shutting
> down","attr":{"exitCode":12}}

I have followed the instructions on "https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/". According to the documentation, I should see a message like this: **"[initandlisten] waiting for connections**
"
I didn't install MongoDB as a Windows Service because I want to use it only as a tool to a personal project.

I have already set the folder in the PATH variable and I executed the command line as a administrator.

I have created the data directories in the *"C:\data\db*" as instructed by the documentation.

If I try "mongo start" in the cmd line I get "*mongo is not recognized as an internal or external command*"

Any help?

Comment: see related to `code":179,"codeName":"WindowsPdhError","errmsg":"PdhAddEnglishCounterW failed with 'O objeto especificado não foi encontrado no computador.'`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47799926/problems-starting-mongodb-on-windows

Comment: as for `"mongo is not recognized as an internal or external command"`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081708/mongo-exe-not-installed-in-version-6-0-0/73084403#73084403

Comment: so the problem with mongo binary that you should download it differently now. As for server starting, based on the link above, it might be started. Do you see a `mongod` process in `Task Manager`?

Comment: No "mongod" in the Task manager...

Comment: have you tried running it again?

Comment: based on this: `{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:20:33.697-03:00"},"s":"I", "c":"NETWORK", "id":23016, "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}} {"t":{"$date":"2022-07-31T19:27:06.517-03:00"},"s":"I", "c":"CONTROL", "id":23372, "ctx":"thread43","msg":"Ctrl-C signal"}`, it worked before, but you manually stopped the process

Comment: I'll check that out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can start MongoDB server with the `mongod.exe` program from theWIndows console/terminal. Once started , you will see the above output (or similar) in the console - that is the log output. You can direct the output to file if you start the `mongod` with the "log file" option. To connect to already started MongoDB server use a tool like `mongosh` or Compass - these are separate downloads.

Comment: Ok, so it's working. The documentation should be more clear though because it says that another message would be displayed when the database successfully started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is normal output, contrary to the documentation which says that `"[initandlisten] waiting for connections "` should be displayed.

Comment: `Waiting for connections` is displayed, you provided it in the logs